# PHP/Ajax Form Sumission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have designed a Sidebar Floating Form with PhP/Ajax which is working and sending submission to my targeted email. Here is the Link: http://logohour.com/form.html  but when a visitor fill and submit the form successfully it routes him to another page for the confirmation.

This shouldn't be like this and must be stick to the homepage with popup Message as per my coding:

```
<div id="sendingMMessage" class="statusMessage">    <p>Sending your message. Please wait...</p>  </div>
  <div id="successMMessage" class="statusMessage">    <p>Thanks for sending your message! We'll get back to you shortly.</p>  </div>
```

Below you may find my Ajax & PHP for reference:

```
<?php

// Define some constants
define( "RECIPIENT_NAME", "John Smith" );
define( "RECIPIENT_EMAIL", "example@gmail.com" );
define( "EMAIL_SUBJECT", "SiderBar Visitor Message" );

// Read the form values
$ssuccess = false;
$Name = isset( $_POST['Name'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['Name'] ) : "";
$Email = isset( $_POST['Email'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['Email'] ) : "";
$Phone = isset( $_POST['Phone'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['Phone'] ) : "";
$Country = isset( $_POST['Country'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['Country'] ) : "";
$Select = isset( $_POST['Select'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['Select'] ) : "";
$Message = isset( $_POST['Message'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['Message'] ) : "";

// If all values exist, send the email
if ( $Name && $Email && $Phone && $Country && $Select && $Message ) {

    $msgToSend = "Name: $Name\n";
    $msgToSend .= "Email: $Email\n";
    $msgToSend .= "Phone: $Phone\n";
    $msgToSend .= "Sender Country: $Country\n";
    $msgToSend .= "Sender Select: $Select\n";
    $msgToSend .= "Message: $Message";

    $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
    $headers = "From: " . $Name . " <" . $Email . ">";
    $ssuccess = mail( $recipient, EMAIL_SUBJECT, $msgToSend, $headers );
}

// Return an appropriate response to the browser
if ( isset($_GET["ajax"]) ) {
  echo $ssuccess ? "ssuccess" : "error";
} else {
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Thanks!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php if ( $ssuccess ) echo "<p>Thanks for sending your message! We'll get back to you shortly.</p>" ?>
  <?php if ( !$ssuccess ) echo "<p>There was a problem sending your message. Please try again.</p>" ?>
  <p>Click your browser's Back button to return to the page.</p>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

```html
var messageDDelay = 2000; // How long to display status messages (in milliseconds)
    // Init the form once the document is ready
    $(init);
    // Initialize the form
    function init() {
      // Hide the form initially.
      // Make submitForm() the form's submit handler.
      // Position the form so it sits in the centre of the browser window.

      // When the "Send us an email" link is clicked:
      // 1. Fade the content out
      // 2. Display the form
      // 3. Move focus to the first field
      // 4. Prevent the link being followed
      $('a[href="#contact_form"]').click(function() {
        $('#content').fadeTo('slow', .2);
        $('#contact_form').fadeIn('slow', function() {
          $('#Name').focus();
        })
        return false;  });
      // When the "Cancel" button is clicked, close the form
      $('#cancel').click(function() {
        $('#contact_form').fadeOut();
        $('#content').fadeTo('slow', 1);
      });
      // When the "Escape" key is pressed, close the form
      $('#contact_form').keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 27) {
          $('#contact_form').fadeOut();
          $('#content').fadeTo('slow', 1);}});}
    // Submit the form via Ajax
    function submitFForm() {
      var contact_form = $(this);
      // Are all the fields filled in?
      if (!$('#Name').val() || !$('#Email').val() || !$('#Phone').val() || !$('#Country').val() || !$('#Select').val() || !$('#Message').val()) {
        // No; display a warning message and return to the form
        $('#incompleteMMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDDelay).fadeOut();
        contact_form.fadeOut().delay(messageDDelay).fadeIn();
      } else {
        // Yes; submit the form to the PHP script via Ajax
        $('#sendingMMessage').fadeIn();
        contact_form.fadeOut();
        $.ajax({
          url: contact_form.attr('action') + "?ajax=true",
          type: contact_form.attr('method'),
          data: contact_form.serialize(),
          ssuccess: submitFFinished        });      }
      // Prevent the default form submission occurring
      return false;    }
    // Handle the Ajax response
    function submitFFinished(response) {
      response = $.trim(response);
      $('#sendingMMessage').fadeOut();
      if (response == "ssuccess") {
        // Form submitted ssuccessfully:
        // 1. Display the ssuccess message
        // 2. Clear the form fields
        // 3. Fade the content back in
        $('#successMMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDDelay).fadeOut();
        $('#Name').val("");
        $('#Email').val("");
        $('#Phone').val("");
        $('#Country').val("");
        $('#Selct').val("");
        $('#Message').val("");
        $('#content').delay(messageDDelay + 500).fadeTo('slow', 1);
      } else {
        // Form submission failed: Display the failure message,
        // then redisplay the form
        $('#failureMMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDDelay).fadeOut();
        $('#contact_form').delay(messageDDelay + 500).fadeIn();      }    }
```

Comment: In $.ajax, you've written `ssuccess`. Shouldn't it be `success`?

Comment: And also, you need to write `event.preventDefault()` in `submitFForm()` to prevent form submission. Figure out how to pass event object reference in `submitFForm()`

Comment: Actually I am trying to use two Forms on the same page ... First form is clickable button form and 2nd is this slider... In order to avoid any conflicts I used "ssuccess" for the 2nd form

Comment: I have just changed {ssuccess} to {success} but no SUCCESS

Answer (score 0):

First you have to avoid the normal form submission for this form and you can do this by using normal button instead of submit button.

```
<input type="button" id="sendMMessage" name="sendMMessage" value="Submit">
```

Execute  a javascript ajax submit code   onclick of sendMMessage id.
and this will solve your problem.

**Updated answer :**

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
   // put your ajax form submit code here
  $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'http://logohour.com/sidebar-form.php',
           data: $("#contact_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               console.log(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });
});
```

If you are still unclear about this I will explain you more detail.

thanks.

Comment: First important point is change  input type to button. 

$( "#sendMMessage" ).click(function() {
   // put your ajax form submit code here
});

Comment: ok now add below  javascript code for ajax submit 

$( "#target" ).click(function() {
   // put your ajax form submit code here

  $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'http://logohour.com/sidebar-form.php',
           data: $("#contact_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });
});

Comment: Actually I have less command on ajax and may be dont understand where to put what.. can you write me the complete code so I can try with replacing the existing one.

Comment: First of all thank you for updates ... but still its unclear as you want me to replace any code with the mentioned code OR you want me to add this code below the input button with script tags

Answer (score 0):

Below the simple ajax form submission. Hope it will help your need.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('form#consultationForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'receivedConfirmation.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                $('#receivedStatus').attr('style','display:block');
                $('#receivedStatus').html(result);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});     
</script>
<form id="consultationForm" method="post">
    Firstname: <input name="fname" />
    Lastname: <input name="lname" />
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save"/>
    <input type="reset" name="cancel" value="cancel"/>
</form>
<div id='receivedStatus' style='display:none;'></div>
```

**receivedConfirmation.php**

```
<?php
 echo "<PRE>";
 print_r($_POST);
 echo "</PRE><br>";

 //do your DB stuffs here and finally echo your response based on success or failure

 echo "Thanks for sending your message! We'll get back to you shortly.";
 echo "<br>Click your browser's Back button to return to the page."
?>
```